# Preparing input for genealogytree

Tags: genealogytree, genealogy

The [documentation for genealogytree](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf) says in section 7.1 (Database Concept):

> The content producer could be a human person directly, but more
>   presumably a machine like a genealogy program. The node content is
>   written as a comma separated key-value list. This list is processed
>   and its content formatted by a database processor.

But are there any examples of code for genealogy programs to output in a format suitable for genealogytree? I have used genealogytree several times and have really liked the output, but only with handwritten input. Now when I want to use data from a GEDCOM file (the most usual format for exchanging genealogical data) I thought that I remembered some (experimental?) code for importing data from a GEDCOM file that came with genealogytree, but it seems like I remember wrong (or it is no longer there).

Comment: I have also found this script in a comment to another answer: https://github.com/mikkelee/genealogytree-mkgraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the recently released version 4.2.7 [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/) has a new genealogytree report category which makes pdfs using genealogytree. It doesn't use all features of genealogytree, but you can take the generated LaTeX file and modify it.

Comment: I was looking around for the LaTeX file accompanying the exported PDF but could not find it. Could you please post a hint how you intercepted it while exporting the report? I am using Gramps on Windows 10 if it is of any help...

Comment: @sophros Actually I've used a prerelease of this functionality. And then when a Gramps was released that had this I thought it was time to mention that here, but I've kept using the prerelease.

Comment: I see. Now, could you please elaborate how to intercept the LaTeX file in the process of generation of the PDF?

Comment: There is a choice for format where you choose between "PDF" and "LaTeX file".

Answer (score 8):

Well, there is no program I know of that you could use (currently).

For private use, I do have a such a program which outputs `genealogytree` compatible code, but it is not based on GEDCOM and not suitable for publication. But you may take this information as *proof of concept* that an automatism could work, even if I know that this must be frustrating.

I strongly believe that there **should** be some software in future that transforms a GEDCOM file (with some selected proband) into `genealogytree` source code. I see the following paths:

- Direct export out of a genealogy program. I had the (weak) hope that some author would implement such an export module into his/her software (*hey, I can use this free tree drawing for my software*), but I do not know of any yet.
- Implementation of `gedcom2latex` as student thesis. Well, I did not find a student yet who is willing to do it (and provide the result as freeware or open source).
- Implementation of `gedcom2latex` by you or anybody else who thinks: *why does this tool not exist?*
- Implementation of `gedcom2latex` by myself. Actually, I don't need it, because I have my private solution, but I'm tempted to do it for eternal glory ;-) I did not have enough time to follow this path yet...

There in an open-source GEDCOM parser http://gedcom4j.org which could be used for `gedcom2latex` to build an internal tree which is to be exported as `genealogytree` source...

Comment: Thanks! I only mentioned GEDCOM, but actually I use Gramps, and if I made something myself for my own needs that would be only for Gramps XML files. I have only looked very cursory on how they look, but it looks like it wouldn't be very hard.

(Maybe just a sentence about the situation would be good in the documentation. Like "At the time of writing no such publicly available programs are known.")

Comment: Do you plan on making the private program which outputs genealogytree-compatible public? Especially for large family trees, this would greatly enhance the usability of the package (no matter how „immature“ the code is). I‘m currently in the same position as OP in that I have the family tree data in whatever way (graph, GEDCOM) as transfer this way is easy, but it is taking quite some time to implement the Genealogytree logic (especially when multiple trees need to be combined)

Comment: @Narusan No, my private genealogy software is too specific to be published in any way. Maybe, some of the tools from https://github.com/T-F-S/genealogytree/wiki/Auxiliary-Tools could be helpful, e.g. the Gramps plugin or the genealogytree-mkgraph Perl script? (or the answers to the questions).

Answer (score 5):

The OpenSource tool [**generations**](https://github.com/jojomi/generations) offers export to genealogytree compatible code with options like **limiting the generations** to consider or the **type of data** to include (no middlenames? sure! no dates of divorces? as you like! no images? your choice!). You can change the **LaTeX templates** used to create the output you need.

The database is a yml file, no GEDCOM support yet (but would technically be possible to develop).

Example for a single database entry:

```
- id: PachGerd1954
  gender: male
  name:
    first:
    - Gerd
    last: Pachowski
  birth:
    date: "1954-07-04"
    place: Bottrop
  mom: PachGise1921
  dad: PachDiet1919
  partners:
  - partner_id: "GöhlMela1954"
    marriage:
      date: "1975-07-01"
    divorce:
      date: "1990-03-09"
```

Generated genealogytree database entry:

```
g[%
id=PachGerd1954,
    rootnode%
]{
    sex = male,
    name = {%
            \pref{Gerd}\ %
        \surn{Pachowski}%
    },
    birth = {1954-07-04}{Bottrop},
        marriage- = {1975-07-01},
        divorce- = {1990-03-09},
}
```

Feedback and MRs are welcome!

*Disclaimer: I am the author of generations.*

Comment: Please include an example showing how your tool outputs compatible code.