# Data input in LaTeX possible?

Tags: xetex, luatex, input

For my next project, I want to check my options.

I would like to create a lexicographic book with genealogical data as a PDF, probably in XeLaTeX but I am open for suggestions. The book shall contain genealogical data and be structured like a lexicon.

While I know basically how to write the LaTeX code to design the pages etc., I do not know whether LaTeX is able (or designed for) to have some kind of "data input".

When I write "data input" I mean that I would like to have a [GEDCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEDCOM) file "read" by LaTeX so that it takes the data and places them in the designed parts in the book.

My first intuition, however, is to write a python script (I do not know other programming languages) and have it pass the data to LaTeX.

Is XeLaTeX or LuaTeX, however, able to handle "data inputs" in some way?

Bonus: what document class would you suggest to write a lexicographical book with not too fancy design in mind? The "good old" book class or "up-to-date" classes like memoir or scrbook, or else?

Comment: You can either let python generate LaTeX code directly or you could try and see if [`datatool`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) fits your needs

Comment: Also have a look at pythontex

Comment: There are tons of GEDCOM tools for python [around](https://github.com/topics/gedcom), so use that and [pythontex](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/pythontex_quickstart.pdf). Also: Unless you have special requirements, the good old book class is good to go.

Comment: if you are familiar with python you will find that easier but you certainly could parse gedcom in tex, also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377690/preparing-input-for-genealogytree

Comment: Luatex contains lua and can naturally handle data input, so you could also look if you can find some GEDCOM lua library.

Comment: Are there any, Ulrike Fischer? A quick research did not reveal any to me...

Comment: Both `scrbook` and `memoir` can be used just like `book` with the default settings, so there’s no downside if you find their defaults acceptable. They make it more convenient to do things like change fonts around and decide whether sections and subsections appear in the table of contents. The `memoir` class, last I checked, was more insistent about setting up the layout the way the author of the class likes it, so I haven’t used it much. I personally like `scrbook`.

Comment: The second google hit was https://github.com/dlaurie/lua-gedcom.